# Parsing EDI file in IIB V10

Tags: edi, hipaa

I am very new to IIB V10 and am starting to work on it for a new project.
I need to parse EDI 999 file in IIB. Is there any node/component to do so? I will have multiple Success/Failure in y EDI 999 file and I need to parse them in IIB using some node and then go forward in the message flow.
I read that there is an HIPAA EDI parser but not much information is available on it. Is there a parser node or a component in IIB that can be used?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that IIB v10 supports EDI processing? Here what I found: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ibm-integration-bus-support-x12-transactions-ie-hipaa-bill-karounos

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure out any component in IIB V10 that would do EDI parsing for me. But I just used a Java Compute node and did the parsing using Java code.

Comment: If you succeeded in realizing what you aimed to (even with a Java Compute Node), you can post it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JavaCompute node in IIB V10 and do the EDI file parsing in Java. I found EDIReader parser the easiest.